# Java GUI in NetBeans on Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, osx-mountain-lion

I'm currently studying a module at university about programming in java.

The IDE we are using is NetBeans and I am using Mac OS X 10.8

We have just started making a application that utilises a GUI.

I am following a worksheet and have followed it exactly.

Currently I am stuck because when I run my application the project builds fine but the GUI does not open when I run it.

My Project is built up of multiple packages and classes and I have set the GUI class as the main class.

Even more confusing to me is that I copied the project over to my Window 7 VM and it built and ran fine and the GUI came up.

Can anyone help as to why the GUI does not open on OS X and if there is a solution.

**EDIT:**

I get the following exception when I try to run my app on a Mac:  http://pastebin.com/cySzY5Wr

Comment: I tried out a sample JFrame with a JPanel and JLabel. It came up fine. Can you paste some relavant code or additional info? What does your main GUI class contain? Is it a JDialog or a JFrame?

Comment: What Exceptions are you seeing, if there are any.. What are your command line options? Copy the jar file into a folder and just try java -jar myApp.jar and see what you get

Comment: @AbhishekGirish I am using a JFrame. The application is designed to keep track of stockitems by showing them in a list. At the moment I have set up test data to appear in the list view. This is all the code I have written in the gui class http://pastebin.com/5F8AzDu3

Comment: @srini.venigalla I just noticed this comes up when I run the application. http://pastebin.com/cySzY5Wr

Comment: You're having a problem with your JDK version based on the comment you made under the answer.  Do you have any idea what JDK version you _intended_ to develop your project for?

Comment: What version of Java do you have on your Mac?  What version of java is your code written for?  What JDK do you have on your Mac?

Comment: @user1766713 - Looks like a problem with your java version. Do you know what jdk version you _intended_ to develop your code for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans builds you application for a specific version of Java. However when you run the applicaton it will fail to run because the executables are of a previous version. To change the target JDK/Java Version in Netbeans you need to:

1. Go into the `Project Properties`(Right click on the project and select properties).
2. Then select the `Libraries` tab and check the JDK version. On OSX it should be JDK6 unless you've installed JDK7 from Oracle.
3. Then select the `Compile` tab(under `Build`)  and check that the version that Netbeans is compiling for is the same or less than the JDK you are using.

You might also want to check the version of Java that you are running in the system(as this will be the version that is used when you double click on the `.jar` file.). You can do this by opening up `Terminal.app`(or search in Spotlight) and typing `java -version`.